# PDF thumbnails don't work

Tags: 11.04, pdf, thumbnails

For a reason I don't know my ubuntu doesn't show thumbnails for pdf.

*in gconf-editor ->-> /desktop/gnome/thumbnailers:*
application@pdf/command = "evince-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o"
application@pdf/enable = "True"

from console `evince-thumbnailer file.pdf out.png` works perfectly
What can be wrong??

when I installed gnome3 thumbnails worked but everything else didnt.
when returned to gnome2.3 - no thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

After many removals and reinstallations of gnome and document viewer something good happened and thumbnails are working.